# Finding subtended angle at the centre of a circle from known arc length

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, angle, arc-length

I have the question "What angle is subtended at the center of a circle of radius $2$ km by an arc of length $9$ m?"

I am not sure  which formula to use to find the subtended angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any circle:

$${ arc=radius*\theta}$$

Where theta is in radian.

From the given data:

$${\theta=arc/radius=0.009/2=0.0045 radians}$$

Comment: 9 = 2 * X         So X = 9/2     So angle = 4.5 is this correct ?

Comment: No, its not. Keep the units in mind. I completely missed that point. Thanks to Robert Z

Comment: Yh it's 9/2000 haha thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Recall that the length of an arc of a circle and the corresponding angle subtended at the centre are proportional.

Comment: So is it 9 ? Or what I put below ? Thanks.

Comment: it should be 9/2000 radians (see the units)

Comment: Should the final answer then be 4.5 X 10^-3 [m] or do I have to leave it as 4.5 X 10^-3 [radians] ? Thanks.

Comment: Why m? The SI unit of plane angle is radian, so you have to answer in terms of radians.

Comment: Okay thanks so it should be 4.5 X 10^-3 [rads] then ?

Comment: Yes $ 4.5 \times 10^{-3} [rads] $ is OK